# Scaling with css3 in a way that it is not occupying old space

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm doing an animation on my web app. I actually want to scale some elements with CSS3 `scaleY(0.5)`.  The elements are in a vertical list, so I don't want them to occupy old space?
How can I acheive that?

I know a solution using wrapper that wrap around the scaling elements and assign new heights to them, but are there any easier solutions that you know?

Comment: It sounds like you can just use HTML layout to let the layout change when you scale the items down and let it resize automatically, but you'd have to be using the right type of HTML/CSS to allow for that.  We can really only help if you show us the HTML/CSS that controls the layout.

Comment: Could you give us a code sample? I'm having a hard time visualizing the exact sequence of events.

Comment: What is "old space"?Are you saying the containers are not scaling with the content?

Answer (score 0):

Use a wrapper with overflow:hidden if you want to restrict it to absolute space...